# PowerBuilder Composite Datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I've got an composite datawindow with 2 reports, one in the detail band and the other one at the summary. My expected result is that the report in the detail band comes first and when that has reached it's end then the other report starts. However this is not the case, the report in the summary overlaps the detail report.

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification: I have 2 reports in my Composite, the problem was that they were shown above eachother even though I had them in different bands. They were actually drawn wrong.

After some experimentation I found out it was the way I populated the reports. I populate them at the same time within a for-loop. I made the guess that the Composite then can't figure where the first one ends so the other one can start. I've made composites with SQL-reports before, this error can't occur then.

The solution was to populate the report at the top first, and at the same time add data to a temporary datastore. When I was done looping, I copied the data from the datastore to the report at the bottom of the Composite and that gave me the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by comes first?  Finishes retrieving or graphically overlaps?  Composites, by definition, are multiple DW reports.  You can't control their order?  Have you set each group to autosize?

Comment: Found out the answer my self, it was because I populated both reports at the same time.